# Add new line to python df cell

Tags: python, pandas, linefeed

I have very strange situation. I have df where I want to do add new line using df.replace. However I got much more new lines what is needed. I want to add new line '\n' when there is '.,' on the df. It seems to add new line also when there is only ',' and oddly enough will remove the previous character.

```
import pandas as pd
names = {'Name': ['Doe, J., Smith, A., Noname, S.', 'Anderson, S., Dude, B.']}
df = pd.DataFrame(names)
print(df)
df = df.replace({'Name' : '.,'}, r'.,\n', regex=True)
print(df)
```

That looks like that:
Name
0  Doe, J., Smith, A., Noname, S.
1          Anderson, S., Dude, B.
Name
0  Do.,\n J.,\n Smit.,\n A.,\n Nonam.,\n S.
1              Anderso.,\n S.,\n Dud.,\n B.

There is probably a very simple solutions but I cannot find it out. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable regex (or escape dot `\.`) to match a real dot else it matchs any characters.

```
>>> df["Name"].str.replace('.,', '\n', regex=False)
0    Doe, J\n Smith, A\n Noname, S.
1            Anderson, S\n Dude, B.
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you, this add new line after dot '.' removing it, but not after comma '.,' And when I add the comma in the script it's broke again. I don't want to remove anything from my field, just add line feed after ., string.

Comment: That \. was helpful information. Sorry I might have miss that from the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Credit belongs to Corralien.

```
df["Name"].str.replace('\.,', '.,\n', regex=True)
0    Doe, J.,\n Smith, A.,\n Noname, S.
1            Anderson, S.,\n Dude, B.
Name: Name, dtype: object
```